# All the 5 positive integers that the product of their digits is 600?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

How many 5-digit positive integers have the property that the product of their digits is 600?

I know that this problem is based on Combinatorics, but I can't think of the approach and calculation part. Any sort of help is appreciated.
I did upto the Prime Factorisation of 600, i.e. $2^3 \times 5^3\times 3$.

Comment: What are the possibilities for the digits of your number? Not $2,2,2,3,5,5$, that's for sure.

Comment: Well, two of the digits must be $5$ since there is no other way to get the factors of five to appear in the number as digits.  So, that is two of our five digits already decided.  We have three digits left to choose.  $4\times 3$ is too big, so we either have our factor of $3$ occurring by itself or as a $6$...  So, it is either $55381, 55342$ or $55641, 55622$ or one of the rearrangements of these.  Can you continue from there?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an edit): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help.

Answer (score 1):

You have the $6$ numbers ${2,2,2,3,5,5}$ in the prime factorization if $600$. Now, consider any $6$ digit number with these numbers, for instance-
$${5~5~3~2~2~2}~~~\text{where,}~5\times5\times3\times2\times2\times2=600.$$
Now, for a $5$ digit number one of the digits has to be removed. However, you need to keep the product of digits equal and deleting a digit would change the final product. The way to achieve that is to club two digits such that their product forms a single digit. To understand this better, look at this 'clubbing' in the number given above-
$$5\times5\times3\times2\times(2\times2)=600~~~\text{giving,}~5~5~3~2~4$$
since, $2\times2=4$, a single digit number.

Hence, simply note the possibilities where the clubbing results in a single digit product for the two numbers allowing us to replace two of them with that number. We only have-
$$2\times2=4~\text{and}~2\times3=6.$$
Therefore, the possible digits for the required number involve digits-

1. $4,2,3,5,5$: total number of possible numbers with these digits $=5!/2!$
2. $2,2,6,5,5$: total number of possible numbers with these digits $=5!/(2!2!)$

Now, note that the prime factorization of any number can easily be modified to include a $1$, since it makes no change in a product. We can as a result, perform clubbing in two ways since, we have $7$ numbers to choose from-
$$5\times5\times3\times(2\times2\times2)\times1=600~~~\text{giving,}~5~5~3~8~1$$
$$\text{or,}~5\times5\times(3\times2)\times(2\times2)\times1=600~~~\text{giving,}~5~5~6~4~1$$
Total number of possible numbers with these digits is equal to $5!/2!$ for each case.

Sum up number of permutations possible casewise to get the final answer.

Comment: Your answer is wonderful and well explained! However, on MathSE, in case of no-context questions like this, it is not a good practice to write a full solution. You may give them hints, so that **they** think and solve, and not you.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 will keep it in mind, thanks!